# How to create an image of maximum pixel values from an input layer-stack image in ERDAS Imagine?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

I have 12 MODIS images (one of each month). I want to create a single image having maximum annual pixel values for each pixel. I did layer stacking operation in Erdas Imagine 13, but how to extract the maximum pixel value ?

Comment: Are you open to a QGIS or ArcGIS solution?

Comment: It would be great if you can help me to solve it using ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also complete this analysis using ArcGIS or QGIS.  If you are using indices derived from MODIS, just add them into the queue.  Otherwise, you will need to separate the MODIS bands prior to adding them to the queue.

1. In ArcGIS, use the [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) tool.
2. In QGIS, use the [r.series](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.series.html) tool in the GRASS toolkit.